# SwiftUI PDF Kit not filling available view space

Tags: pdf, swiftui

I have a SwuftUI view that has both a Nav bar and Tab bar.  I have a PDF viewer that loads a PDF via URL.  When the PDF is displayed in the view it starts below the Navbar which is desired but it doesn't fill down to the top of the Tab Bar despite the pdf being multiple pages long.  I know I could use `.frame()` and make the view full height then subtract height of both bars, but that seems so ineffecient.

[image: iOS Screenshot]

There must be a simpler way to do this, calculating the height up fixed UI elements just to make the view fit correctly seems very inefficient.  Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

PDFViewer.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFViewer: View {
    var url: URL
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
            .navigationTitle("Payslip")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userIsAuthenticated: Bool = false
    
    init(auth: State<Bool>) {
        navAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color("MyBlue"))
        navAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navAppearance
        
        self._userIsAuthenticated = auth
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if userIsAuthenticated {
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    RosterView(auth: $userIsAuthenticated)
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .tabItem { Label("My Roster", systemImage: "calendar") }
                
                NavigationView {
                    PayView(auth: $userIsAuthenticated)
                }
                .tabItem { Label("My Pay", systemImage: "dollarsign.circle") }
                
                NavigationView {
                    LeaveView(auth: $userIsAuthenticated)
                }
                .tabItem { Label("My Leave", systemImage: "airplane.circle") }
                
                NavigationView {
                    MessagesView(auth: $userIsAuthenticated)
                }
                .tabItem { Label("Messages", systemImage: "bubble.left.and.bubble.right") }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .accentColor(.white)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
                UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "MyBlue")
                UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightText
                UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
            })
        } else {
            AuthView(auth: $userIsAuthenticated)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in another part of your code. If I test your code in the following way, the frame of the PDFViewer is correct.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var url: URL {
        guard let localURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A Sample PDF",
                                             withExtension: "pdf")
        else {
            fatalError()
        }
        return localURL
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                PDFViewer(url: self.url)
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "folder")
                    Text("Test")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right.  One of my list views is performing the same behaviour which has nothing to do with the PDFKit so I'll have to do some digging

Comment: Just checked and removed all `.frame()` adjustments from views and all of them are behaving in this way.  I have tried nesting with `TabView` in the `NavigationView` and this fixes the issue, all the list reach the full height however this causes issues where I can't set Nav properties since the `TabView` is the child object.  I've added `ContentView.swift` to the original question.

Comment: Found it.  `UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` was causing the behaviour for some reason.  I'm pretty sure that isn't the intended behaviour